# Display properties for overlaying images

Tags: html, css

I've a slideshow which is done overlaying many images and using javascript to change their opacity and attributes. You may see it here:

http://www.openpost.it/gallerie/paola-di-bella-microaree-per-post-n3/

As you can see (using firebug), on change there's something that doesn't work. The two images overlays only when the `display` properties  of the first one is set to `none`. Otherwise, the second image is shown just below the first one and only when the first one disappears it's moved to its right position.

Which css property should I use in order to place the second image in the same place of the first one? I've tried to modify the display properties in many different ways, but I haven't achieved any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing "position: relative !important" from ".ngg-slideshow *"
:

```
.ngg-slideshow * {
...
// position: relative !important;
...
}
```